# Convergence of a series, what is wrong with my solution?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have just attempted the following question

> Show that if $ (b_n) _{n \in \mathbb N }$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R $, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }b_n2^{-n}$ is convergent.

This is my solution.

> If $(b_n)$ is bounded then $\exists M \in \mathbb R$ such that  $\lvert b_n \rvert \le M$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. Then, by taking every term in the following series to be
> $M$ and the fact $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}$ converges to 1, we deduce that
>
> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } b_n2^{-n} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } M2^{-n} = M
> $$
>
> Therefore, by the comparison test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } b_n2^{-n}$ converges.

However, the official solution uses Cauchy sequences and partial sums. Is there a major flaw in my solution?

Comment: I see no flaw - remember that solutions in texts are just one way to solve problems. Other techniques may be used. Good on you!

Comment: You are missing an absolute value. Not applying Comparison test correctly. But your method works fine with one correction.

Comment: but $b_n \in \mathbb N$, so it can't be negative?

Comment: @DS Maybe you are confused by notation $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. This notation states that the *indices* $n$ are natural numbers. Not the $b_n$. At first hand it was not okay (which explains your confusion) but now it is repaired by means of an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$b_n$ may be negative, so you cannot use the comparison test, which works for series with non-negative terms. So you may take absolute value to conclude that the series $\sum|b_n|2^{-n}$ converges by comparison test, and the original series converges since it converges absolutely.

Comment: but $b_n \in \mathbb N$, so it can't be negative?

Comment: As explained by drhab, $b_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$(i.e. $b_1, b_2, b_3, \cdots$) are just real numbers. They can be negative.